# mysql fulltext stripslashes not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, stripslashes

I want to perform this mysql search :

```
 SELECT ida, MotsClef FROM Actes WHERE MATCH (MotsClef ) 
 AGAINST ('+"dette" +"plège"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Using php, I use regular expressions to add the +" and " to the expressions received via $_POST so a var_dump gives :

```
'motcle' => string '+"dette" +"plège"'
```

So that's fine too. However, I use prepared statements using PDO class and I have this piece of code for that:

```
 if($r['motcle']!=''){
     $motclef = $r['motcle'];
     $demMotsClef = " AND WHERE MATCH (MotsClef ) AGAINST (:motsclef IN BOOLEAN MODE) ";
    }
    else{
            $demMotsClef='';
    }
```

than:

```
 $f = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Actes, Bibliographie WHERE id = idBiblio".$demMotsClef;

$demande = $this->prepare($f);

if($r['motcle']!=''){$demande->bindValue(':motsclef',stripslashes($motclef));}

$demande->execute(); //the error is on this line//
```

I get a MySQL error message saying I have an error in your SQL syntax:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near 'WHERE MATCH (MotsClef ) AGAINST 
('+\"dette\" +\"plège\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND a' at line 1' in 
/Library/WebServer/Documents/messources/actions.class.php on line 547.
```

The error in mysql syntax is that the slashes are added, hence the use of stripslashes (doesn't work).

Any idea on how to solve that - I would rather not change ini settings either in php.ini or in a .php function since that would mess up all my other mysql requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the full error you're getting please ? Would help a lot.

Comment: Okay, and how is your "prepare" in php, can you show os that line too ?

Comment: The only conceivable situation where `stripslashes()` comes in handy is when you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled but they were never a good idea and they were removed some years ago. Said that, the parse error is at `WHERE`... because `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar AND WHERE gee` is clearly wrong SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh, well took me a while to find the error but this is definetly wrong:

```
$demMotsClef = " AND WHERE MATCH (MotsClef ) AGAINST (:motsclef IN BOOLEAN MODE) ";

$f = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Actes, Bibliographie WHERE id = idBiblio".$demMotsClef;
```

If you look at this, you'll have double WHERE, which is not allowed, you should make this change:

```
$demMotsClef = " AND MATCH (MotsClef ) AGAINST (:motsclef IN BOOLEAN MODE) ";
```